# Mongoose : Subtract a variable from values in an array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I need to modify the values in an array in all documents by a variable amount. Lets take a sample schema:

```
var BookSchema = new Schema({
  id : String,
  values : Array
});
```

And `values` is an array object items, which have the form `{publisherName, cost}`. Publisher name being a string, cost being a number.

Now, I have a cron job in which I want to decrease the value of the cost by a random amount of less than five dollars ( `Math.round(Math.random()*5)`), for all books. How do I do this? I read the documentation, closest I could find was the `$` operator, but that lets me set a field, and not decrease it by a variable amount.

Edit: I forgot to mention I'm trying to do this in one update. Otherwise, as Oleg said, this can be done through read-modify-save.

Comment: And how is setting the field differs from "changing" the field as a decrease will lead to a changed value? Do you want to here the answer to how to loop through your data changing values or the answer to how to update a filed in data behind the schema?

Comment: Because from the examples I've seen, setting a field assigns a value, instead of a subtraction as in this case. In other words, my example needs "cost = cost - randomDecrease", while the "$" and "$set" operators are of the type "cost = newcost". Hope I could convey that properly.

Comment: And what is wrong with the sequence of: read, modify, set? Or your idea is to solve it without reading a value? This would not be a problem if your new value was independent of the old one, but it is not: it is in fact a decrement by a random amount, so one way or another you need to read it (even if it ends up to be some sort of predicate on a db value itself).

Comment: Ah, my bad. I forgot to mention I was trying to do this in one single update operation. While reading the docs, it felt just out of reach, so I thought I might be missing something. The alternative is as you said, read-update-save. But I thought I'd ask first.

Comment: "A common problem with non-relational database is that it is not possible to do transactions across several documents." and "MongoDB provides atomicity for an operation on a single document" from http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/perform-two-phase-commits/